# ManyToOne mapping gives null

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

When I call `itemModel` from stock class, `itemModel` is `null`. I already mapped foreign key and so, I don't know what's wrong.

### Model1

```
    @ManyToOne(optional=false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="item_stock", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private ItemStcok itemModel;
```

### Model 2

```
@Entity
@Table(name="item_stock")
public class ItemStcok {

    //constructor
    //getter setter
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ItemStcok [itemId=" + itemId + ", itemName=" + itemName + ", category=" + category + ", unit=" + unit+ ", price=" + price + ", totalQty=" + totalQty + ", reorderLevel=" + reorderLevel + "]";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please post complete entity classes

Comment: Have a look at simple example and then try yourself https://github.com/AtulDwivedi/holy-hibernate/blob/master/src/com/atuldwivedi/learn/hibernate/association/manytoone/